# Какие способы есть для сжатия JSON данных на стороне клиента перед отправкой на сервер?

Tags: json, javascript, zip

При получении данных с сервера можно использовать Gzip, т.е. на сервере включается соответствующая опция или модуль и данные отправляются клиенту в сжатом виде. Как сделать что-нибудь подобное и на клиенте чтобы например при отправке запроса POST'ом данные сжимались?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jsend](http://jsend.org/)

[Демонстрация работы](http://jsend.org/demo/)

Comment: крутотень!

Comment: Сам лично не пользовался, но использовал кто-то из знакомых, в итоге отказались по причине неуловимых багов, посему используйте на свой страх и риск :)

И еще - имеет смысл использовать только тогда, когда отправляете действительно большой объем данных одним запросом, в противном случае игра не стоит свеч